# how to verify whether computer is already exist in AD or not

Tags: powershell, script, active-directory, vbscript

I am looking for a script which find the machine guid and search in Active directory whether it is exist or not

If exist 
provide me their "distinguish name"

I am looking for a powershell script but it is not recommended.

Note: I will be running this script in Window PE before joining the domain

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you mean it's not recommended? What's your script so far? For the search in the AD you'd just use `Get-ADComputer` I guess.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

its nice to include examples you've tried but

```
Get-ADComputer -Identity (objectGUID)
```

this will put it into the pipeline as a Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADComputer type

What you do with it now is up to you. (pipe it to Get-member for options)

Using an example objectguid what you asked could be done like this

```
Get-ADComputer -Identity x00xx000-0000-000x-00xx-00000x00000x0 | select name
```

you'l get an error if it can't find the device.

```
Get-ADComputer : Cannot find an object with identity:
```

this could obviously be done a lot nicer but this is very basic and it should work.